# Symbol 0 undefined error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4, flashdevelop

I use Flashdevelop.

I am trying to import a symbol from another file.
[Embed(source='test.swf', symbol="new_game")] protected var new_game3:Class;

I get 
Error: Unable to create source rc_new_game3.: symbol 0 not defined
[Embed(source='test.swf', symbol="new_game")] protected var new_game3:Class;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wvxvw was on the right track, it was caused by swf file.
Some parameters were not set, for a button, it was not given what is the Up/Over/down/Hit state....

Answer (score 3):

This means that Flex SDK wasn't able to understand what Flash compiled into the test.swf. Things to try:

- upgrade Flex SDK.
- search for "suspicious" symbol names in flash - eliminate all non-alphanumeric, non-latin characters from names in the library.
- shape tweens and some linestyles are known to cause linking errors to Flex compiler. Shape tweens may usually be cured by breaking the animation into frames, linestyles can be cured by "breaking apart" (Ctrl+B) the graphics containing them.